# Sorting of XContainer based on attribute value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Can any one help me to sort the XmlDocument based on attribute value.

I have given a sample xml having few attr elements. So I want to sort it based on "value" attribute of elements having attribute Name="from" I am trying to achieve this using linq to xml.

Here is one sample code I  tried. But it is retaining only the "from" attributes in sorted order. I want all the attributes as shown below under expected xml.

```
container.ReplaceNodes(
            from childEl in container.Elements().Elements()
            where childEl.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "from"
            orderby childEl.Attribute("Value")?.Value descending
            select childEl
        );
        foreach (XElement childEl in container.Elements().Where(e => e.HasElements))
    {
        SortByName(childEl);
    }
```

Input XML:

```
`<Attrs>
  <Attr Name="zddressprevious" isVerified="false">
    <Attr Name="from" Value="2014-01-01" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="house" Value="3" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="street" Value="Test Street" isVerified="false" />
  </Attr>
  <Attr Name="addressprevious" isVerified="false">
    <Attr Name="from" Value="2015-01-01" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="house" Value="1" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="street" Value="Acacia Avenue" isVerified="false" />
  </Attr>
  <Attr Name="addressprevious" isVerified="false">
    <Attr Name="from" Value="2016-01-01" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="house" Value="1" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="street" Value="Test Street" isVerified="false" />
   </Attr>
</Attrs>`
```

Expected output:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Attrs>
  <Attr <Attr Name="addressprevious" isVerified="false">
    <Attr Name="from" Value="2016-01-01" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="house" Value="1" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="street" Value="Test Street" isVerified="false" />
   </Attr>
   <Attr Name="addressprevious" isVerified="false">
    <Attr Name="from" Value="2015-01-01" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="house" Value="1" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="street" Value="Acacia Avenue" isVerified="false" />
  </Attr>
  <Attr Name="zddressprevious" isVerified="false">
    <Attr Name="from" Value="2014-01-01" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="house" Value="3" isVerified="false" />
    <Attr Name="street" Value="Test Street" isVerified="false" />
  </Attr>
</Attrs>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LINQ` statement has to return the **parent element** (of the one containing the from-attribute) via `childEl.Parent`.

From your question is not completely clear whether your container is an `XDocument`or an `XElement`.

In case of an **`XElement`** the `LINQ`statement looks like:

```
var q =
    from childEl in container.Elements("Attr").Elements("Attr")                
    where childEl.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "from"
    orderby childEl.Attribute("Value")?.Value descending
    select childEl.Parent
    ;
```

and the replace as:

```
container.ReplaceNodes(q);
```

Note that the `LINQ` statement without explicitly specifying the `Attr`element names will also do the job:

```
var q =
    from childEl in container.Elements().Elements()                
    where childEl.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "from"
    orderby childEl.Attribute("Value")?.Value descending
    select childEl.Parent
    ;
```

In case of an **`XDocument`** your query must look like:

```
var q =
    from childEl in container.Element("Attrs").Elements("Attr").Elements("Attr")                
    where childEl.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "from"
    orderby childEl.Attribute("Value")?.Value descending
    select childEl.Parent
    ;
```

and you have to replace the nodes via:

```
container.Element("Attrs").ReplaceAll(q);
```